# how to find a string and an indeterminate number of lines up and down for the string given

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, grep

Im using grep to find a string and an indeterminate number of lines up and down of this string until match a double break line. For example, in a document where i have something like this:

```
Name: Alice
ID: 6969
Interests: foo,bar

Name: Bob
ID: 5555
Interests: foo,bar
Experience

Name: Carl
ID: 3236
Interests: foo,bar
```

I want to find all information about a person by the ID, so if i look for 5555, the output i want is:

```
Name: Bob
ID: 5555
Interests: foo,bar
Experience
```

I have tried using `grep -C n ID_string` (where n is the number of lines up and down to match for string given) but the output is a fix number of lines "n" and I want the until double break of line. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\S/{h;:a;n;//{H;$!ba};g;/5555/p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

Begin a collection of lines in the hold space when the current line contains a non-space character.

End the collection on a blank line or the end of file.

Test the collection for the required string and if it matches print the entire collection. Repeat.

---

To add a newline to the result, use:

```
sed -n '/\S/{h;:a;n;//{H;$!ba};z;H;g;/5555/p}' file
```

---

Sed is a stream editor. It is used to edit text files and normally processes a line of text at a time. It has two buffers it uses to accomplish this task. The pattern space (PS) and a spare buffer called the hold space (HS). The normal flow of events is that sed reads a line of text into the PS and strips its newline. Sed instructions (commands) act on the PS, the stripped newline is re-appended and the result is delivered to the stdout i.e. printed.

The `-n` option turns off the implict nature of delivering the PS to stdout i.e. if you want to print something out you must issue a command to do so, such as `p` or `P` which prints the PS or prints the first line of the PS.

Sed uses regexp to decide if to apply commands to the PS. The `/\S/` is a regexp that tests the PS for any non-whitespace character. Sed uses parens to group commands and commands are separated by semi colons.

The `h` command replaces whatever was in the hold space (HS), by the contents of the PS.

Sed can perform loops. It does this by defining a place holder to loop to and a command to break to the loop place holder. The `:a` defines a loop place holder named `a` and the `b` is the break to command.

The `n` command fetches the next line into the PS. Normally this would cause the contents of the PS to be pushed on to stdout before it was replaced, but because the `-n` option is on, its contents is just thrown away.

The `//` is shorthand for the previous regexp i.e. the contents of the PS is now tested again for a non-whitespace character and if so the commands within parens are executed. In this case, the `H` appends the PS to the HS separated by its newline that was stripped beforehand.

Sed knows the line number of each line and it also knows when the last line of a file is present in the PS. The `$` denotes the last line. The `!` is the not command and negates the previous address or regexp e.g. `$!` means not the last line of the file. Putting it all together `$!ba` means, if it is not the last line of the file, break `b` to the place holder `a`. Thus the command flow is directed back to `:a` and sed resumes processing from there.

If the `//` is not matched, this infers two possibilities, either the current line is empty or it is the last line of the file. `z` zaps the PS and empties it. `H` appends the empty line to the HS delimited by a newline.

`g` replaces the PS with the contents of the HS. The collection of line(s) which the loop has built up is now in the PS. Another regexp tries to match on the PS `/5555/` and if so issues the `p` command which prints the PS.

Thus the sed program moves through the file gathering up collections of non-empty lines in the HS and printing them if a regexp matches.

Comment: Thank you so much this work perfectly! Can you be a bit explicit in the explanation please? I'm new with scripting tools. An another question, if I want print the last "\n" what must add to the regex? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)ID: 5555(\n|$)/' file
Name: Bob
ID: 5555
Interests: foo,bar
Experience
```

A couple of examples of using this same approach to find other combinations of values from fields:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)Name: [[:alpha:]]*[aA].*(\n|$)/' file
Name: Alice
ID: 6969
Interests: foo,bar

Name: Carl
ID: 3236
Interests: foo,bar

$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)Name: [[:alpha:]]*[aA]/ && /(^|\n)ID: 6/' file
Name: Alice
ID: 6969
Interests: foo,bar

$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)Name: [[:alpha:]]*[aA]/ && /(^|\n)ID: [0-9]+6(\n|$)/' file
Name: Carl
ID: 3236
Interests: foo,bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^Name/{
  if(found){
    print value
  }
  value=found=""
}
{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0
}
/ID:/{
  if($NF==5555){
    found=1
  }
}
END{
  if(found){
    print value
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
/^Name/{                            ##Checking if a line starts with Name then do following.
  if(found){                        ##Checking if found is SET then do following.
    print value                     ##Printing variable value here.
  }
  value=found=""                    ##Nullifying value and found values here.
}
{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0      ##Creating value here which will have all lines value separated with new line.
}
/ID:/{                              ##Checking if a line has ID: then do following.
  if($NF==5555){                    ##Checking condition if last field is 5555.
    found=1                         ##Then set found=1 here.
  }
}
END{                                ##Starting END block of this program here.
  if(found){                        ##Checking if found is SET then do following.
    print value                     ##Printing variable value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pcregrep` you could try:

```
cat data.txt | pcregrep -M '(^.+$\n)*ID: 5555\n(^.+$\n)*'
```

With a small tweak you can also separate the returned/displayed matches with a newline for easier reading:

```
cat temp.txt | pcregrep -M '(^.+$\n)*ID: 5555\n(^.+$\n)*\n?'
```

You may need to install `pcregrep`, e.g. using:

```
sudo apt install pcregrep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    !NF{delete buffer;i=0;go_on=0;next}
    /ID: 5555/{
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)print buffer[j]
        go_on=1
    }
    go_on
    {i++;buffer[i]=$0}
' file
```

If you don't want to hardcode neither the ID number nor the file name, save this and make it executable:

```
awk -v number=$1 '
    !NF{delete buffer;i=0;go_on=0;next}
    $0 ~ "ID: " number{
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)print buffer[j]
        go_on=1
    }
    go_on
    {i++;buffer[i]=$0}
' "$2"
```

Then call it `./script 5555 file`.

---

Sample input file:

```
Name: Alice
ID: 6969
Interests: foo,bar

Surname: John
Nickname: Bill
Name: Bob
ID: 5555
Interests: foo,bar
Experience

Name: Carl
ID: 3236
Interests: foo,bar
```

Output:

```
Surname: John
Nickname: Bill
Name: Bob
ID: 5555
Interests: foo,bar
Experience
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl one-liner will do:

```
what=5555 perl -00 -ne '/ID:\s+$ENV{what}/\m and print' file
```

The `-00` switch enable `paragraph` mode. In this mode, each record is a paragraph (block) of text bounded by one or more empty lines.

The paragraph is printed if a line within matches the token `ID:` with one or more trailing whitespace, followed by the value of `what` set when the script is launched. Note that `what` is set only for the duration of the command line.

The `\m` regex modifier causes the `$` to match the end of each line within the string. This creates exact matches for `what`.